# async/await within Express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I have a node/express route that collects information via url parameters. I use these parameters to initiate a separate function which takes a few seconds. I am trying async/await to wait for the function to return data but the route logic just plows ahead, not waiting for anything.

Is this a syntax/structure problem? Any tips are welcome as I seem to have hit a wall. Thanks!

```
app.get('/testlogin', (req, res) => {
  (async () => {
    // This needs to wait until loginToApp returns data but it does not
    await loginToApp(req.query.u, req.query.p)
       .then((data) => {
        console.log('from testlogin route. This should print after loginToApp');
        console.log(data); // the returned data
      });
  })();
});

async function loginToApp(user, pwd) {
  (async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const data = { temp: 1, rtemp: 2 };
      console.log('from loginToApp');
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    }, 2000);
  })();
}
```

Comment: Your `loginToApp` function doesn't `await` anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `loginToApp` function needs to return a `Promise` for you to `await`. If using a `setTimeout`, then you'll have to explicitly wrap it in a new Promise.

```js
app.get('/testlogin', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await loginToApp(req.query.u, req.query.p);
  console.log(data);
});

async function loginToApp(user, pwd) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const data = { temp: 1, rtemp: 2 };
      console.log('from loginToApp');
      console.log(data);
      res(data);
    }, 2000);
  })
}
```